# How to know in python if a data frame with date format is included within a time interval (Vectorizing)

Tags: python, pandas, time, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following dataframe:

```
index       arrivalTime
0   01/11/2016 06:53:15 
1   01/11/2016 06:55:25 
2   03/11/2016 16:57:10
3   03/11/2016 16:57:30 
4   04/11/2016 18:58:10
5   06/11/2016 19:58:35 
6   08/11/2016 20:00:05
```

I need know the rows that are between 16:00:00 and 20:00:00 in the different days. I give an example the results:

```
index       arrivalTime result
0   01/11/2016 06:53:15      0
1   01/11/2016 06:55:25      0
2   03/11/2016 16:57:10      1 
3   03/11/2016 16:57:30      1
4   04/11/2016 18:58:10      1
5   06/11/2016 19:58:35      1
6   08/11/2016 20:00:05      0
```

I get the above results using apply function and one nested function but it is very slow and I would like to do it "vectorizing" but I can not.

```
def function_time(df):

    df['hora_lle'] = df['arrivalTime'].map(lambda x: x[-8:])

    def class(hora_lle):

        x = dt.datetime.strptime(hora_lle, '%H:%M:%S').time()
        h1 = dt.datetime.strptime('16:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
        h2 = dt.datetime.strptime('20:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

        if x < h1:
            return 0
        elif h1 <= x < h2:
            return 1
        elif h2 <= x:
            return 0

    df['seg'] = df['hora_sal'].apply(class) 
    return df
```

Thanks you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then create `mask`, which is converted to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), but this solution not works if `minutes` and `seconds` are `0`:

```
df.arrivalTime = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalTime) 
h = df.arrivalTime.dt.hour  
mask = (h > 15) & (h < 20)
df['result'] = mask.astype(int)

print (df)
   index         arrivalTime  result
0      0 2016-01-11 06:53:15       0
1      1 2016-01-11 06:55:25       0
2      2 2016-03-11 16:57:10       1
3      3 2016-03-11 16:57:30       1
4      4 2016-04-11 18:58:10       1
5      5 2016-06-11 19:58:35       1
6      6 2016-08-11 20:00:05       0
```

Similar solution with [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) - extract times and then compare them:

```
df.arrivalTime = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalTime)   

h1 = dt.datetime.strptime('16:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
h2 = dt.datetime.strptime('20:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
times = df.arrivalTime.dt.time
mask = (times >= h1) & (times <= h2)
df['result'] = mask.astype(int)
print (df)
          arrivalTime  result
0 2016-01-11 06:53:15       0
1 2016-01-11 06:55:25       0
2 2016-03-11 16:57:10       1
3 2016-03-11 16:57:30       1
4 2016-04-11 18:58:10       1
5 2016-06-11 19:58:35       1
6 2016-08-11 20:00:05       0
```

---

Another solution with [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) which works only with [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) - output is assign to column `result` and tested for [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df.arrivalTime = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalTime) 
df['result'] = 1
df.set_index('arrivalTime', inplace=True)
df['result'] = df.between_time('16:00', '20:00')
df['result'] = df['result'].notnull().astype(int)
print (df)
                     result
arrivalTime                
2016-01-11 06:53:15       0
2016-01-11 06:55:25       0
2016-03-11 16:57:10       1
2016-03-11 16:57:30       1
2016-04-11 18:58:10       1
2016-06-11 19:58:35       1
2016-08-11 20:00:05       0
```

Comment: Nice one as always haha !